# Loop to display random posts only if a  custom field matches category

Tags: custom-field, loop, query

Working on a website and need loop that will show posts ONLY if custom field value is equal to the current category name.

I have category 'fun' and custom field 'genre'. I would like to show on custom archive page only posts that are selected to be under category 'fun' AND at the same time if the value in custom field 'genre' is 'fun'. Order I prefer is most visited posts first at the top - if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should be the query you want to run, it adds a condition to the page query that requires the value in "meta_field" to equal the current category's title.

```
global $wp_query;
$args = array('meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'meta_field',
        'value' => single_cat_title("", false),
        'compare' => '='
    )
  )
);

query_posts(array_merge($wp_query->query, $args));
// The Loop Goes Here //
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, but I get
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')'
At the last few lines, I can't figure out why...

Comment: `global $wp_query;
$args = array('meta_query' => array(
  array(
   'key' => 'meta_field',
   'value' => single_cat_title("", false),
   'compare' => '='
  )
 )
);

query_posts(array_merge($wp_query->query, $args));
// The Loop Goes Here //` 

here you go... one ")" was missing

Comment: Thanks for catching that, I've updated my answer with the correction

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel, I said I am noob :) Thanks Dave too, this code works perfectly.

Comment: Hey Dave & Daniel, how would I add `('orderby' => 'rand')` to this query? Or even better order by popular posts first?

Comment: Well the question is what is considered "popular" post. By views? by Comments? any other way?

This is by random order:

`global $wp_query;
$args = array(
 'post_status' => 'publish',
 'orderby'  => 'rand'
 'meta_query' => array(
  array(
   'key' => 'meta_field',
   'value' => single_cat_title("", false),
   'compare' => '='
  )
 )
);

query_posts(array_merge($wp_query->query, $args));`